# Is this Salary Transparency calculator accurate for inexperienced developers?

Tags: discussion

Stack Overflow has issued [a page](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/07/salary-transparency/) called "Salary transparency at Stack Overflow", with a [calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/company/salary/calculator) that calculates the expected salary based on your experience and skill.

Let's look at the worst, ever salary of a developer with ZERO experience and ZERO skill:

[image]

I'm really surprised by this!  I'm now thinking, why is Stack Overflow doing this?

- Does it just want to make every developer in the world feel bad and overused?
- Does it want companies to increase salaries?
- Are the guys who created these calculations not good at statistics?
- Are the error bars like 200% the salary value?

Please feel free to suggest more possibilities in the comments!

Seriously, with no offence whatsoever to this website that I love and highly appreciate. What is this supposed to be? I'm really confused! And not only me... just look at all the comments on that page and on Stack Overflow's Facebook page! Almost all the comments are making fun of this!

Comment: I imagine being employed by a company like Stack Overflow is fairly selective. This is the salary at SO; not average across all companies.

Comment: Perhaps they value their employees more than other companies? Did you take a look at the site they linked to as inspiring their particular tool? https://buffer.com/salary Their salaries are decently high too. I don't see comments making fun of this. Both companies seem to be doing just fine and recruiting good employees.

Comment: @TZHX Well, I don't think so... You're telling me that a company gives a newbie with 0 experience absolutely no skills 3x the salary just because... I'm sorry, I don't believe that! You'd attract most people with 10% more... not 300%.

Comment: I'm saying I doubt the company in question would hire someone with absolutely no skill or experience. Why don't you believe that?

Comment: 0 skill in terms of SO doesn't mean no skills. It may look a little misleading, but reading the "more info" part and playing with the provided skill calculator clears it out.

Comment: @gdziadkiewicz Well even with some skills... call them academic skills... let's say someone who just finished their bachelor. Does such a guy get in his first day 300% the normal salary? Even 200%? This is extremely odd! It sounds like a publicity attraction lie!

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I'm wondering from where you are from ? This kind of salary could be really disturbing in France for example where there's a bunch of taxes not counted in the raw salary, that's different in the US and may lead to some hard time comparing salaries.

Comment: @Tensibai I'm from Germany. 30% of my salary goes to taxes, and I'm putting taxes into account and comparing the salary before taxes.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Are you taking in account what your company pays too ? (in france this is something like 40% of raw salary added to the salary itself), I.e: If  I gain net 60, my salary is 100 and my company pays something around 140 at the end of the day. If I were to work for a US company as consultant, I had to pay the 80 more than my net gain by myself, this change the ratio (even if it's higher than median salary in France anyway)

Comment: @Tensibai That makes sense actually. If that's the case, then I stand corrected.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist  "Work Taxes" in Europe are far different than in the US, I can only compare with French system as it's the only one I'm sure of. I've no idea on how it is in Germany, so this worth a digging to ensure.

Comment: US companies usually have to pay over and above salary as well, but not as much (apparently) as european companies.  Found an org that calculates these costs (scan down for charts) http://bit.ly/1l84MKK Of course, we get less government benefits in the US (for example, I don't have to visit a [VA hospital for my healthcare](http://www.politico.com/story/2014/05/veterans-administration-scandal-106982), and don't clear anywhere near the total salary amount (shared health insurance costs, taxes, etc).  So while we get more money up front, we do have to pay more on the other side.

Comment: Pulling in some thoughts from reddit: The salary numbers seem reasonable. Compared to other places, they are a bit high on the low-end and low on the high-end. High on the low-end is expected if SO is really selective. Low on the high-end is also the case if you compare with places like Google or anything in finance where the "high-end" can be upwards of $1m+ for total comp.

Answer (score 15):

Stack Overflow's base salary being $86,000 does not mean that anyone can just get a job there with zero skill or experience.

If you see what it actually says, *professional* experience, that means someone could have theoretically been programming for years and years, just not ever as their career. So they'd have to put zero for that, even though they might be able to program circles around you.

And if you click through the "More Info" link next to skill, you'll see what they mean by that. It's not literally "no skill in programming". The Skill metric covers all kinds of general work life aspects.

The bottom line is not that Stack Overflow will give the neighborhood dog walker an $86,000 job if they apply and want to become a programmer (I've got a couple years of programming experience "professionally" already and 10k reputation, and I don't think I'd be hired by them as a developer at this point, personally).

They will still hold what I imagine is a very thorough job interview after an already rigorous selection process. If they like what they see and believe you are capable of doing the job, $86,000 is what they will start you at, everything else aside.

Comment: Also yes I imagine Stack Overflow believes companies should pay their developers more than they already do, all things considered. They're quite evangelistic about the value of programming to the world (which is a good thing).

Comment: SO doesn't pay it's employees lots of money because they're altruistic and think that developers should just be paid more; they pay lots of money because they want the best developers in the world, and paying lots of money is one of the ways in which they strive to attract the best developers in the world.  It's a decision in their own self-interest (not that there's anything wrong with that).

Comment: What I find crazy is that, for a dev they would pay ~180k/year, they would only bump the salary 15k if they work in SF, NY or London.  Using a random cost of living calculator on the internets (totally legit no doubt), even with that 15k bump, it's like losing 100k/year compared to living cheaply but comfortably in a non-insane city.  SF is pretty, but I'd work remote, thankyouverymuch.